# OpenXML - continue writing to next worksheet (million row hit)

Tags: excel, openxml, datareader

According to Microsoft [specifications](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) .xlsx files have limit of 1,048,576 rows **PER worksheet**. In theory, as I see It, that means we could write file even with 2 million of rows - with two worksheets in same workbook.

I'm using OpenXML package with SAX approach, which (imho) is still best for writing large Excel files. I also extended my solution to write `.xlsx` file directly from DataReader in order to avoid any Out Of memory exception, because our users usually export very large amount of data.

That being said, I'm facing an issue when users want to export data larger than 1,048,576 rows - as .xlsx limit is (yes, they actually export that amount).

Currently they can do It with 2 steps by creating separate .xlsx files, but I'm wondering If that could be done in a single file?

For the code part: I've set a variable which checks row number (`row_number`) and if it hits 1 million then a new worksheet should be created, in order to continue writing data from same DataReader to the next sheet.

However I'm facing issues when creating new sheet, as my data is being written by `OpenXmlWriter`, which already holds a `Sheetpart` instance for sheet1. As I see it, maybe this would work If I could pass a reference of sheet2 to `OpenXmlWriter`:

```
int row_number = 0;

using (var Excel_doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(file_path, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
      var workbookPart = Excel_doc.AddWorkbookPart();

      Excel_doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook
      {
             Sheets = new Sheets()
      };

      var sheetPart = Excel_doc.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

      //Add sheet
      Sheets sheets = Excel_doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
      string relationshipId = Excel_doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

      uint sheetId = 1;
      if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
      {
         sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
      }

      Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "Sheet " + sheetId };
      sheets.Append(sheet);

      using (var XML_write = OpenXmlWriter.Create(sheetPart))
      {
          XML_write.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet()); 
          XML_write.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

          //Writing data using DataReader...
          using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                 XML_write.WriteStartElement(new Row());

                 for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                 {
                      row_number++;
                 }
                 XML_write.WriteEndElement(); //End of row

                //If 1 million row exceeded then proceed writing to next sheet - here is where I'm stucked
                if (row_number>1000000)
                {
                    sheetId +=1;   
                    Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "List " + sheetId };
                    sheets.Append(sheet1);

                    XML_write.WriteEndElement(); 
                    XML_write.WriteEndElement(); 
                    XML_write.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet()); 
                    XML_write.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());
                    row_number=0;
                 }
              }
          }
          XML_write.WriteEndElement(); 
          XML_write.WriteEndElement(); 
          XML_write.Close();
      }
}
```

While writing `.xlsx` file this code terminates with an error:

> Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment

I would be more than happy If anyone has a solution to this, or a suggestion to make It work.

P.S.: Something similar already exists in some solutions - e.g. Toad for Oracle, which exports into .xls file on multiple sheets after hitting max 65k rows. So probably It can be done.

Comment: I would advise to generate an Excel file which contains a connection to the datasource in its data model so the user might create a pivottable (which is what I would expect them to do anyway), rather than dumping the data on worksheets.

Comment: @jkpieterse, actually users export that amount of data because they need to send It forward to another organisations, containing whole data. Only regular Excels file with data in rows are allowed, I don't have any infulence on that. Neither I don't know what they do with It. But just of curiosity - do you have any link of examples for that ? Maybe (just maybe) someday my suggestion may have been noticed ;)

Comment: No examples, but you can record a macro while manually performing the steps quite easily to get sampe VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to swap the order of the loops, basically. Open your connection, then create a sheet and use it until a counter hits 1 million, then close it and create another.

Here's some basic pseudocode.

```
count = 0
sheet = new
writer = new writer(sheet)
using (reader)
{
    foreach (row in reader)
    {
        if (count % 1,000,000 == 0)
        {
            writer.close
            sheet = new
            writer = new writer(sheet)
        }
        writer.write(reader.read)
        count++
    }
}
writer.close
```

Comment: thanks for this, I'll take a try, It looks promising. It's gonna take some time though, actual code is a lot longer than my example provided. But worth trying, I'll let you know once finished. I will accept answer after that, thanks again :)

Comment: I've finally made It :).... It's a little more complicated than your example because you need to do many other things with OpenXML code too, but in principle your answer is correct. So thanks again !!

Comment: Hi @Lucy82 could you please share some info about how you have achieved it? I may need the same functionality to export more than 1M rows.

Comment: @ozdogan, sorry for late reply, but complete code is quite long. If you still need It you can contact me and I'll send It to you. There are many adjustments in OpenXML that needs to be done.